# Как лучше хранить сокеты в андроид-приложении?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Подскажите, как лучше хранить переменные сокетов в андроид-приложении. Мне необходимо обращаться к ним из разных мест приложения. Они могут быть инициализированы только из фонового потока.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Объявление в фоновом сервисе переменной `static String` не подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно какие именно переменные. Например мы можем создать класс с константами и с ним общаться откуда вам нужно:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String SOME_NAME = "test";
}
```

второй вариант создать поле в build.gradle и к нему обращаться ([документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code)). Этот вариант я лично использую для отлова типа сборки приложения и выбора соответствующего адреса сервера:

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // These values are defined only for the release build, which
      // is typically used for full builds and continuous builds.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${minutesSinceEpoch}\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "${minutesSinceEpoch}")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      // Use static values for incremental builds to ensure that
      // resource files and BuildConfig aren't rebuilt with each run.
      // If these rebuild dynamically, they can interfere with
      // Apply Changes as well as Gradle UP-TO-DATE checks.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "0")
    }
  }
}
```

и можно их получить:

```
Log.i(TAG, BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME)
Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.build_time))
```

еще как вариант - использовать SharedPreferences. Такой вариант подойдет если данные не будут меняться, доступ к ним не навредит вам и вашему приложению. То есть например если это имя пользователя - можно его сохранить и тащить после перезагрузки приложения из памяти. Если же вы хотите сохранить адрес сервера - лучше использовать build.gradle файл. Если же у вас эти переменные будут меняться то статичные поля вам не подойдут - создайте класс с необходимыми вам полями и инициализируйте их в нужный момент и потом вытаскивайте где вам нужно.